# Installing 'mtr' with tce package manager

Tags: linux, software-installation, make

I'm trying to install 'mtr' (https://github.com/traviscross/mtr) on Levinux (http://mikelev.in/ux/). Levinux only has the 'tce' package manager and does not include the 'make' command.

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `compiletc`. Install it with the command `tce-load -wi compiletc.tcz`. That package includes `make`, as well as other compilation tools like `gcc` and all the standard headers (`stdio`, `stdlib` etc.). For more information see [tce-load](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:tce-load) (on the Tiny Core Linux wiki) and the [list of TCE packages avaliable](ftp://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/tce_2x.html).